# What's the difference between "Regular Height" and "Any Height" in Compact Width in Size Classes?

Tags: ios, size-classes

In `Compact Width`, `NSLayoutConstraints` declared in `Any Height` have the the same effect of the ones applied to the `Regular Height` class.

[image: img1]

What are the differences between those classes?

Comment: I think maybe it's just a semantic distinction. If you create a Compact Height layout for landscape iPhone, then you can't really call the Portrait one "Any" anymore, can you? Also, there are use cases for Compact/Regular width, so having Compact/Regular height as a pairing just keeps the system balanced & consistent. Last thought - This leaves things flexible for future devices that have different form factors. The option is already there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That makes sense. Post this as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @CeceXX, where did you get that (original) image? I need to print that out. Thanks!

Comment: A two second search led me to it, sorry! http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe it's just a semantic distinction. If you create a Compact Height layout for landscape iPhone, then you can't really call the Portrait one "Any" anymore, can you? Also, there are use cases for Compact/Regular width, so having Compact/Regular height as a pairing just keeps the system balanced & consistent. Last thought - This leaves things flexible for future devices that have different form factors. The option is already there.